# How can I book the Accesrail air-rail intermodal solution ticket?

Tags: air-travel, uk, trains, intermodal

The [Accesrail website](http://www.accesrail.com/sc/first-great-western.html) states:

> First Great Western now provides, thanks to AccesRail, its first air-rail intermodal solution. This allows passengers to go to/from Heathrow or Gatwick Airport to their First Great Western destination of choice.
>
> Passengers receive an intermodal ticket that covers both their flight and rail journey. Depending on which airport the passenger travels, train connections are slightly different.

As a passenger, how do I purchase such an intermodal ticket?  Accesrail does not seem to sell them.  There is [rail-fly.com](http://rail-fly.com) but that seems to cover only flights to Singapore.

Comment: Did you try asking your friendly local travel agent? The website you link to seems to have all the details for a clueful travel agent to be able to make the booking for you

Comment: @Gagravarr I didn't, I was wondering if there is a way to book it myself online.

Comment: Online is generally great for simple stuff, this very much doesn't look like simple... [The Official BA announcement about it on FlyerTalk](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/23922522-post4.html) only mentions booking through Travel Agents, neither the BA website nor other websites got a mention as a route

Comment: When SJ+SAS did this in Sweden a while ago it was all bookable online.

Answer (score 3):

The accesrail site lists IATA airport codes for the train stations.  I've tried putting those into flight-search engines and even the sites belonging to the airlines that accesrail mentions as participating, and they don't recognise them, so I think the only answer is to use a travel agent.

Note that the airport codes do not match the UK rail station codes, e.g. Bristol Temple Meads is BRI on UK rail, but TPB on IATA - if you put BRI into a flight-search engine, you'll end up in Bari.